# Is there a known O(nm)-time/O(1)-space algorithm for POSIX filename matching (fnmatch)?

Tags: c, regex, string, pattern-matching, substring

**Edit:** WHOOPS! Big admission, I screwed up the definition of the `?` in `fnmatch` pattern syntax and seem to have proposed (and possibly solved) a much harder problem where it behaves like `.?` in regular expressions. Of course it actually is supposed to behave like `.` in regular expressions (matching **exactly one** character, not zero or one). Which in turn means my initial problem-reduction work was sufficient to solve the (now rather boring) original problem. Solving the harder problem is rather interesting still though; I might write it up sometime.

On the plus side, this means there's a much greater chance that something like 2way/SMOA needle factorization might be applicable to these patterns, which in turn could yield the better-than-originally-desired `O(n)` or even `O(n/m)` performance.

---

In the question title, let `m` be the length of the pattern/needle and `n` be the length of the string being matched against it.

This question is of interest to me because all the algorithms I've seen/used have either pathologically bad performance and possible stack overflow exploits due to backtracking, or required dynamic memory allocation (e.g. for a DFA approach or just avoiding doing backtracking on the call stack) and thus have failure cases that could also be dangerous if a program is using `fnmatch` to grant/deny access rights of some sort.

I'm willing to believe that no such algorithm exists for regular expression matching, but the filename pattern language is much simpler than regular expressions. I've already simplified the problem to the point where one can assume the pattern does not use the `*` character, and in this modified problem you're not matching the whole string but searching for an occurrence of the pattern in the string (like the substring match problem). If you further simplify the language and remove the `?` character, the language is just composed of concatenations of fixed strings and bracket expressions, and this can easily be matched in `O(mn)` time and O(1) space, which perhaps can be improved to `O(n)` if the needle factorization techniques used in 2way and SMOA substring search can be extended to such bracket patterns. However, naively each `?` requires trials with or without the `?` consuming a character, bringing in a time factor of `2^q` where `q` is the number of `?` characters in the pattern.

Anyone know if this problem has already been solved, or have ideas for solving it?

Note: In defining O(1) space, I'm using the [Transdichotomous_model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transdichotomous_model).

Note 2: This site has details on the 2way and SMOA algorithms I referenced: http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/index.html

Comment: Are you sure you mean O(1) space? This sounds like an unreasonable 4restriction. There's a modification to the shift-or pattern matching algorithm that handles wildcards — I take it you are aware of that? — Scatch that, you said O(nm) time so it's not unreasonable.

Comment: Indeed, it would be great if I could get O(n) time or even better O(n/m), but I just asked for O(nm). I think that *may* be reasonable but I'm not sure. As long as it's not as bad as the usual exponential time of backtracking, I'll be somewhat happy. I think you may be right that O(1) space is too much to expect (even with my qualification of transdichotomous model), but I believe I may have just worked out a solution with `O(log q)` space (where `q` is the number of question marks in the pattern) and as-yet-unknown time characteristics.

Comment: Well, the shift-or algorithm variant would have running time O(n+|Σ|) assuming a small enough needle (which is the common assumption) and require O(|Σ|) space, with Σ being the alphabet. However, this is for greedy wildcards. I’m uncertain whether POSIX wildcards are more powerful.

Comment: Calling `m` `O(1)` is kind of cheating... :-)

Comment: For POSIX `fnmatch`, the pattern is not searched for as a substring in the string; it's required to match the whole string. `?` and `*` can match as many or few characters as it takes to do that. For `*`, what I'm doing is partitioning the pattern into `*`-separated units (consider the boundary components separately) and for each unit, attempt to find the match that ends the earliest in the string. Since it's immediately followed by a `*`, this can never result in a matching failure, and it gives the most matching possibilities for subsequent parts in what remains of the string.

Comment: (Where "as many or as few" for `?` means 1 or 0.)

Comment: I'd be intrigued to hear about your solution with `O(log q)` space. By the way, in the transdichotomous model, shouldn't `O(log q)` be equal to `O(1)`, since `O(1)` space is assumed to be enough to store an index to the input string (and `q` is necessarily bounded by the length of the input)?

Comment: No, because it's actually `O(log q * log log q)` or something like that if you throw away transdichotomous... ;-)

Comment: I see... well, as I say, I'd be intrigued to see what you have in mind!

Comment: I'll write it up as soon as I get a chance. I have an ugly time bound that seems better than exponential but it's not sharp and not very good.

Comment: Hey all, got an embarrassing admission I just added to the question and my answer. They're not wrong, but I was trying to solve a harder problem that's unnecessary to the task at hand. On the bright side, much better performance is probably possible, maybe even `O(n/m)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's how I solved the problem.

1. Attempt to match the initial part of the pattern up to the first `*` against the string. If this fails, bail out. If it succeeds, throw away this initial part of both the pattern and the string; we're done with them. (And if we hit the end of pattern before hitting a `*`, we have a match iff we also reached the end of the string.)
2. Skip all the way to end end of the pattern (everything after the last `*`, which might be a zero-length pattern if the pattern ends with a `*`). Count the number of characters needed to match it, and examine that many characters from the end of the string. If they fail to match, we're done. If they match, throw away this component of the pattern and string.
3. Now, we're left with a (possibly empty) sequence of subpatterns, all of which are flanked on both sides by `*`'s. We try searching for them sequentially in what remains of the string, taking the first match for each and discarding the beginning of the string up through the match. If we find a match for each component in this manner, we have a match for the whole pattern. If any component search fails, the whole pattern fails to match.

This alogorithm has no recursion and only stores a finite number of offsets in the string/pattern, so in the transdichotomous model it's O(1) space. Step 1 was O(m) in time, step 2 was O(n+m) in time (or O(m) if we assume the input string length is already known, but I'm assuming a C string), and step 3 is (using a naive search algorithm) O(nm). Thus the algorithm overall is O(nm) in time. It may be possible to improve step 3 to be O(n) but I haven't yet tried.

Finally, note that the original harder problem is perhaps still useful to solve. That's because I didn't account for multi-character collating elements, which most people implementing regex and such tend to ignore because they're ugly to get right and there's no standard API to interface with the system locale and obtain the necessary info to get them. But with that said, here's an example: Suppose `ch` is a multi-character collating element. Then `[c[.ch.]]` could consume either 1 or 2 characters. And we're back to needing the more advanced algorithm I described in my original answer, which I think needs `O(log m)` space and perhaps somewhat more than `O(nm)` time (I'm guessing `O(n²m)` at best). At the moment I have no interest in implementing multi-character collating element support, but it does leave a nice open problem...

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into the `re2` regular expression engine by Russ Cox (of Google)?

It's a regular expression matching engine based on deterministic finite automata, which is different than the usual implementations (Perl, PCRE) using backtracking to simulate a non-deterministic finite automaton. One of the specific design goals was to eliminate the catastrophic backtracking behaviour you mention.

It disallows some of the Perl extensions like backreferences in the search pattern, but you don't need that for glob matching.

I'm not sure if it guarantees `O(mn)` time and `O(1)` memory constraints specifically, but it was good enough to run the Google Code Search service while it existed.

At the very least it should be cool to look inside and see how it works. Russ Cox has written three articles about `re2` - [one](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html), [two](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp2.html), [three](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp3.html) - and the [`re2` code](http://code.google.com/p/re2/) is open source.

Comment: Presumably, though, creating the DFA requires dynamic memory allocation, which R.. is specifically looking to avoid...

Comment: Indeed. DFA obviously solves the time problem well but has a major space problem. The `regcomp`/`regexec` interfaces make this acceptable by having a way to report allocation failure separate from matching failure, but `fnmatch`'s interface implicitly always succeeds, so depending on allocation can't really meet the interface contract.

Comment: @R..: You *could* always use the fast algorithm, but if allocation fails fall back on the slow.  Too much hassle?

Comment: @StephenCanon: The problem is that the known slow algorithm **also** has pathological space requirements (`O(m)` on the stack, which can overflow).

Comment: With that said, actually I was thinking about the ability to swap-in a faster matcher when I designed the algorithm described in my answer. For each `*`-flanked component, it's possible to first attempt allocating a DFA for the component, and only fallback to my matching algorithm if the allocation fails. Of course I'm not sure if that's beneficial; I think my algorithm will be very fast in the reasonable-size pattern cases, and only potentially slow when the number of `?` characters becomes insanely large.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** WHOOPS! Big admission, I screwed up the definition of the `?` in `fnmatch` pattern syntax and seem to have solved a much harder problem where it behaves like `.?` in regular expressions. Of course it actually is supposed to behave like `.` in regular expressions (matching **exactly one** character, not zero or one). Which in turn means my initial problem-reduction work was sufficient to solve the (now rather boring) original problem. Solving the harder problem is rather interesting still though; I might write it up sometime.

Possible solution to the harder problem follows below.

---

I have worked out what seems to be a solution in `O(log q)` space (where `q` is the number of question marks in the pattern, and thus `q` < `m`) and uncertain but seemingly better-than-exponential time.

First of all, a quick explanation of the problem reduction. First break the pattern at each `*`; it decomposes as a (possibly zero length) initial and final component, and a number of internal components flanked on both sided by a `*`. This means once we've determined if the initial/final components match up, we can apply the following algorithm for internal matches: Starting with the last component, search for the match in the string that starts at the latest offset. This leaves the most possible "haystack" characters free to match earlier components; if they're not all needed, it's no problem, because the fact that a `*` intervenes allows us to later throw away as many as needed, so it's not beneficial to try "using more `?` marks" of the last component or finding an earlier occurrence of it. This procedure can then be repeated for every component. Note that here I'm strongly taking advantage of the fact that the only "repetition operator" in the `fnmatch` expression is the `*` that matches zero or more occurrences of *any* character. The same reduction would not work with regular expressions.

With that out of the way, I began looking for how to match a single component efficiently. I'm allowing a time factor of `n`, so that means it's okay to start trying at every possible position in the string, and give up and move to the next position if we fail. This is the general procedure we'll take (no Boyer-Moore-like tricks yet; perhaps they can be brought in later).

For a given component (which contains no `*`, only literal characters, brackets that match exactly one character from a given set, and `?`), it has a minimum and maximum length string it could match. The minimum is the length if you omit all `?` characters and count bracket expressions as one character, and the maximum is the length if you include `?` characters. At each position, we will try each possible length the pattern component could match. This means we perform `q+1` trials. For the following explanation, assume the length remains fixed (it's the outermost loop, outside the recursion that's about to be introduced). This also fixes a length (in characters) from the string that we will be comparing to the pattern at this point.

Now here's the fun part. I don't want to iterate over all possible combinations of which `?` characters do/don't get used. The iterator is too big to store. So I cheat. I break the pattern component into two "halves", `L` and `R`, where each contains half of the `?` characters. Then I simply iterate over all the possibilities of how many `?` characters are used in `L` (from 0 to the total number that will be used based on the length that was fixed above) and then the number of `?` characters used in `R` is determined as well. This also partitions the string we're trying to match into part that will be matched against pattern `L` and pattern `R`.

Now we've reduced the problem of checking if a pattern component with `q` `?` characters matches a particular fixed-length string to two instances of checking if a pattern component with `q/2` `?` characters matches a particular smaller fixed-length string. Apply recursion. And since each step halves the number of `?` characters involved, the number of levels of recursion is bounded by `log q`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hash of both strings and then compare these. The hash computation will be done in O(m) while the search in O(m + n)

#### You can use something like this for calculating the hash of the string where s[i] is a character

```
s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

As you said this is for file-name matching and you can't use this where you have wildcards in the strings. Good luck!

Comment: I think the question is specifically about matching efficiently *with* wildcards (plain string comparison like this is trivially `O(nm)` time and `O(1)` space).

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that this is not possible.

Though I can't provide a bullet-proof argument, my intuition is that you will always be able to construct patterns containing q=Theta(m) `?` characters where it will be necessary for the algorithm to, in some sense, account for all 2^q possibilities. This will then require O(q)=O(m) space to keep track of which of the possibilities you're currently looking at. For example, the NFA algorithm uses this space to keep track of the set of states it's currently in; the brute-force backtracking approach uses the space as stack (and to add insult to injury, it uses O(2^q) time in addition to the O(q) of space).

Comment: I believe have a binary partitioning cheat whereby accounting for all 2^q possibilities is not necessary. I'll post the outline.

Comment: I've posted it. Hope it's clear. Please comment if you think something's broken about it...